# How to delete a row from core data and table view

Tags: ios

I am getting an error “An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts” while trying to delete an object from the core data.
i am using the below code in the load after the normal core data fetch

```
    NSFetchedResultsController  *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    controller.delegate=self;
    BOOL success = [controller performFetch:&error];


    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
     NSManagedObject *managedObject = [controller objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     //(Alert view)
     }
```

In the alert view clickedButtonAtIndex function , i am trying to delete that particular managed object from the appDelegate.managedObjectContext , but an error “An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts” occurs in the line

```
    [appDelegate.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
```

i tried with other managed object context ,

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context= [controller managedObjectContext];
```

but getting the same error.
Can anyone please tell why this error occurs and a solution to delete a particular row from the table view and the core data?

Comment: Which `managedObjectContext` are you using to store the object? You cannot delete objects in other contexts, as the error says.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a different context to the one the object is from (exactly what the error says), change the delete line to

```
[managedObject.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];
```

Comment: I tried to use this [managedObject.managedObjectContext deleteObject:managedObject];but got error [NSKnownKeysDictionary1 managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfe7e830

Comment: thats a different issue, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835676/ios-coredata-exception-when-updating-data

Answer (score 0):

Use the same NSManagedContext to delete that's used to fetched the objects, and in the same thread also.

Comment: I tried the same NSManagedContext ie,appDelegate.managedObjectContext for fetching the data and deleting , but no use.

Comment: Cross-check that the 'appDelegate.managedObjectContext' is not overwritten !!